# converting string to tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples

I need to write a function that takes a string '(1,2,3,4,5),(5,4,3,2,1)' and returns a list of tuples of the 1st and last element of each tuple, [(1,5),(5,1)].
I was thinking:

```
def f(givenstring):
    a=givenstring.split(',')
    for i in a[0:-1]:
        tuple(int(i[0,-1]))
```

but here I'm stucked..

Comment: Think more like re.findall() or eval() (but remember, eval is evil). Sorry, no time for a full answer.

Comment: Can you fix the code formatting?  (For some reason, I can't..)

Comment: Related: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810109/parsing-a-string-which-represents-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 85):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

In your example:

```
from ast import literal_eval
s = '(1,2,3,4,5),(5,4,3,2,1)'

l = literal_eval(s)
print l
# ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 3, 2, 1))

print [(x[0], x[-1]) for x in l]
# [(1, 5), (5, 1)]
```

Comment: note, AST is python2.6+, I have to use eval on my python2.5 project.

Answer (score 33):

You may use `eval`. I think it'll be the shortest one.

```
>>> s = '(1,2,3,4,5),(5,4,3,2,1)'
>>> ts = eval(s)
>>> ts
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
>>> tsp = [(el[0],el[-1]) for el in ts]
>>> tsp
[(1, 5), (5, 1)]
```

Still, it's **not a good practice** to use `eval`.

Another option is to parse the string using `re` module.

```
>>> a = re.findall('\([^)]*\)',s)
>>> a
['(1,2,3,4,5)', '(5,4,3,2,1)']
```

Regexp pattern means this:

```
\( #opening parenthesis
[^)]* #from 0 to infinite symbols different from )
\) #closing parenthesis
```

.

```
>>> b = [el.strip('()') for el in a]
>>> b
['1,2,3,4,5', '5,4,3,2,1']
>>> c = [el.split(',') for el in b]
>>> c
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']]
>>> d = [tuple(int(el2) for el2 in el) for el in c]
>>> d
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

Also, you may do the following:

```
>>> [tuple(int(i) for i in el.strip('()').split(',')) for el in s.split('),(')]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

This approach takes not modules at all. But it's not very robust (if the input string will have some inconsistency, e.g. space between parentheses and comma `...), (...`, then noting will work).

Comment: yeah, I know.. So I would like to avoid eval.. and I don't really know re.findall, so I would like to avoid that one too, if it is possible?

Comment: is there a way to combine the b,c and d lists comprehension into a single list comprehension?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Sure `[tuple(int(el2) for el2 in el.strip('()').split(',')) for el in a]`.

Comment: @ovgolovin could you please explain why using `eval` should be avoided?

Comment: @Josh It's from security standpoint. `eval` will execute any Python payload, even malicious one.

Comment: @ovgolovin thank you, could you please give an example except for the sql injection case

Comment: @josh here is one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285969/executing-code-through-python-eval

Comment: @Josh Also note, there is `ast.literal_eval` which is safe against injections.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, the `ast` module could be useful:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = '(1,2,3,4,5),(5,4,3,2,1)'
>>> my_tuples = literal_eval(s)
>>> my_tuples
((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
```

So, `my_tuples` has a tuple with the tuples of your string. Now, we can get the first and last element of all your tuples using a list comprehension:

```
>> new_tuples = [(t[0], t[-1]) for t in my_tuples]
>>> new_tuples
[(1, 5), (5, 1)]
```