# Convert String to Tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples

I'm trying to read each line by line and convert each line to tuple as showing in the following exam:

Possible Duplicata:  [Converting String to Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494514/converting-string-to-tuple)

input_1.txt

```
126871 test
126262 value test
```

result.txt

```
('126871', 'test')
('126262', 'value', 'test')
```

**Sample Code:**

```
    def string_to_tuple_example():
        with open('Input_file_1.txt', 'r') as myfile1:
            tuples1 = myfile2.readlines()
            print tuples1 #return string, here I STUCK
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.split`:

```
with open('Input_file_1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print tuple(line.split())

('126871', 'test')
('126262', 'value', 'test')
```

If you want to write these tuples to a file then convert them to a string first using `str`:

```
with open('Input_file_1.txt') as f, open('result.txt','w') as f1 :
    for line in f:
        f1.write(str(tuple(line.split())) + '\n')

>>> !cat result.txt
('126871', 'test')
('126262', 'value', 'test')
```

Comment: Actually I got the same result but want output as a first bracket as result.txt. Thanks.

Comment: @user2412714 I've already mentioned that in my answer, use `tuple(line.split())` if you want a tuple. :)

Comment: @user2412714 see my updated answer, may be that's what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @Ashwini Chaudhary
If I use line.split() then result will be with the third bracket but if I use tuple(line.split()) then the result will be with the first bracket.

Comment: @user2412714 I am not sure what do you mean by third bracket, `str.split` returns a list(`[...]`), if you want parenthesis(`(...)`) then use `tuple()`.