# Tuple and CSV Reader in Python

Tags: python, csv, tuples

Attempting something relatively simple.

First, I have dictionary with tuples as keys as follows:
(0,1,1,0): "Index 1"

I'm reading in a CSV file which has a corresponding set of fields with various combinations of those zeroes and ones. So for example, the row in the CSV may read 0,1,1,0 without any quoting. I'm trying to match the combination of zeroes and ones in the file to the keys of the dictionary. Using the standard CSV module for this

However the issue is that the zeroes and ones are being read in as strings with single quotes rather than integers. In other words, the tuple created from each row is structured as ('0','1','1','0') which does not match (0,1,1,0)

Can anyone shed some light on how to bring the CSV in and remove the single quotes? Tuple matching and CSV reading seem to work -- just need to straighten out the data format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple(int(x) for x in ('0','1','1','0'))    # returns (0,1,1,0)
```

So, if your CSV reader object is called `csv_reader`, you just need a loop like this:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    tup = tuple(int(x) for x in row)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

when you read in the CSV file, depending on what libraries you're using, you can specify the delimiter.

typically, the comma is interpreted as the delimiter. perhaps you can specify the delimiter to be something else, e.g. '-', so that set of digits are read together as a string, and you can convert it to a tuple using variety of methods, such as using [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) mentioned in [converting string to tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494514/converting-string-to-tuple)

hope that helps!