# How can I create tuple from CSV file without quotes?

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I'm reading CSV file and need to make tuples but I need to get rid the quotations. CSV lines examples:

```
57, 47, 1.04
1288, 317, 1.106
149, 84, 1.05
```

I tried this

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

with open('./Documents/1.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
   x = list(map(tuple, reader))
```

and the results are:

```
[('57', '47', '1.04'),
 ('1288', '317', '1.106'),
 ('149', '84', '1.05')]
```

and I need it to be

```
[(57, 47, 1.04183),
 (1288, 317, 1.106),
 (149, 84, 1.05)]
```

Found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810829/tuple-and-csv-reader-in-python) but can't figure out the answer yet.

Comment: You want to convert a string to a float.

Comment: Your problem here is that the numbers are read as strings instead of floats. If your file only contains numbers, consider using numpy.genfromtxt(). Otherwise, pandas.read_csv() is able to handle multiple variable types in one data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to add an extra processing, converting with type casting:

```
reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
# if the file has a header
# header = next(reader)
rows = [[float(row[0]), float(row[1]), float(row[2])] for row in reader]
print rows
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the numbers inside the tuples to their respective types:

```
import csv
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint

with open('1.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
   x = [tuple(map(literal_eval, x)) for x in map(tuple, reader)]
   print(x)
   # [(57, 47, 1.04), (1288, 317, 1.106), (149, 84, 1.05)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def num(s):
        try:
            return int(s)
        except ValueError:
            return float(s)


with open('1.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True)
   output = [tuple(map(num, x)) for x in map(tuple, reader)]
   print(output)
```

output:

```
[(57, 47, 1.04), (1288, 317, 1.106), (149, 84, 1.05)]
```