# Executing code through python eval

Tags: python, eval

My class assignment is to read a file called key.txt on a server which is in the same directory of a python script it is running on port 2323.  The code running in the script is as follows:

```
while 1: print  eval(raw_input("Enter   Math:"))
```

I'm connecting with PuTTY and every time I run any code, the connection instantly drops if the code I pass is invalid.  It gives no explanation, but I assume the eval function couldnt parse my code.

Here are some of the things I've tried and their outputs:

- Entering `open('key.txt', 'r').read()` (or any explicit code) killed the connection
- Using chr(#) to pass in commands, ex. hello = `chr(104)+chr(101)+chr(108)+chr(108)+chr(111)`.  The server just spits back whatever I type
- Using `compile` by entering `compile('print "Hello!"', 'buttfile', 'exec')`, with the output `<code object <module> at 0x7f6270ac0db0, file "buttfile", line 1>`

Those are the only two ways I can think of that allows me to pass in code.  I wrote a small cpp program to convert whatever I type into the char combinations, as well as including newlines so I can enter multiline code with the chr() method.

So my question is how would I execute code to read a file through python's eval function?

Comment: Sorry, added question to body

Comment: Yes but the python code were using works on our systems but not theirs, through 2.7+ versions.  I feel like I'm either missing something big or they messed up somehow.

Comment: Is it a linux system?

Comment: I can't tell because they do provide the web terminal when you go to the server IP.  However, they did not give us any credentials to log in, and made a custom terminal splash screen so I don't know the OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connecting to a linux system you can do it in two commands:

```
__import__("os").system("locate key.txt")
```

This assumes that the locate db is up to date.

Then when you know the location just use:

```
__import__("os").system("cat /location/of/file/key.txt")
```

Which will output the key to the screen.

Comment: Thank you thats perfect! It is a linux system indeed