# Split a string containing multiple tuples into list of string tuples

Tags: python, list, split, tuples

How can I split a string of tuples into a list?

For example I have this `SARIMAX(0, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)` string, and I want to convert it into a list of tuples into this `['(0, 1, 1)', '(0, 1, 1, 12)']`

This is my code:

```
sarimax_res = 'SARIMAX(0, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)'
sarimax_res = sarimax_res.replace('SARIMAX', '').replace('x', '')
```

My output:

```
'(0, 1, 1)(0, 1, 1, 12)'
```

Comment: Is `sarimax_res.replace('SARIMAX', '').split('x')` what you want? Or did you actually want to convert the `'(0, 1, 1)'` and `'(0, 1, 1, 12)'` into real tuples and not just strings?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @wkl Ahh, you're right, I can split it with x and replace SARIMAX

Comment: @JiříBaum I just want split the string of tuples into a list

Comment: What does your *desired* output look like?

Comment: @BeRT2me As on the question. I want convert it into ['(0, 1, 1)', '(0, 1, 1, 12)']

Comment: The issue is, those aren't tuples how you have it written. They're strings.

Comment: This is not a string of tuples ("SARIMAX" is not a tuple, neither is 'x'). To get the desired output you can just take two substrings, but I would assume that's not what you're trying to do so please add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

sarimax_res = 'SARIMAX(0, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)'
tuples = list(map(literal_eval, re.findall('\(.+?\)', sarimax_res)))
print(tuples)

# Output:
[(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 12)]
```

One-Liner for just strings:

```
re.findall('\(.+?\)', sarimax_res)

# Output:
['(0, 1, 1)', '(0, 1, 1, 12)']
```

Comment: Instead of splitting on `', '` in the second stage, it might be better to make it a regex search and split on `r',\s*'`; that depends on the data

Comment: Good to see the result! Thanks, it helps me, actually, I need the list of tuple strings. but anyway thanks!!!

Comment: @RudyTriSaputra added the string only method as well~

Answer (score 0):

`ast.literal_eval` can [safely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494627/3936044) evaluate the string.

We can use it by replacing the x with a comma, making `literal_eval` return a tuple of tuples, since you wanted list it's just cast to a list.

```py
from ast import literal_eval

sarimax_res = 'SARIMAX(0, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)'
sarimax_res = sarimax_res.replace('SARIMAX', '').replace("x", ",")
list(literal_eval(sarimax_res))

>>> [(0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1, 12)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted a list of string tuples you can just split the string on the x like this:

```py
sarimax_res = 'SARIMAX(0, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)'
sarimax_res.replace('SARIMAX', '').split("x")

>>> ['(0, 1, 1)', '(0, 1, 1, 12)']
```