# Convert tuple-strings to tuple of strings

Tags: python

My Input is:

```
input = ['(var1, )', '(var2,var3)']
```

Expected Output is:

```
output = [('var1', ), ('var2','var3')]
```

Iterating over input and using `eval`/`literal_eval` on the tuple-strings is not possible:

```
>>> eval('(var1, )')
>>> NameError: name 'var1' is not defined
```

How can I convert an item such as `'(var1, )'` to a tuple where the inner objects are treated as strings instead of variables?

Is there a simpler way than writing a parser or using regex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810109/parsing-a-string-which-represents-a-list-of-tuples

Comment: @MarounMaroun That doesn't work as I explained. In the question you provided, floats can be evaluated. Strings like 'var1" can't. `literal_eval` will throw a `ValueError: malformed string`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each occurrence of a variable, [`eval`](//docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) searches the symbol table for the name of the variable. It's possible to provide a custom mapping that  will return the key name for every missing key:

```
class FakeNamespace(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key
```

Example:

```
In [38]: eval('(var1,)', FakeNamespace())
Out[38]: ('var1',)

In [39]: eval('(var2, var3)', FakeNamespace())
Out[39]: ('var2', 'var3')
```

***Note:*** `eval` copies current globals to the submitted `globals` dictionary, if it doesn't have `__builtins__`. That means that the expression will have access to built-in functions, exceptions and constants, as well as variables in your namespace. You can try to solve this by passing `FakeNamespace(__builtins__=<None or some other value>)` instead of just `FakeNamespace()`,  but it won't make `eval` 100% safe ([*Python eval: is it still dangerous if I disable builtins and attribute access?*](//stackoverflow.com/q/35804961/2301450))

Comment: Cool approach! Although we should be careful sanitizing input if using `eval()`.

Comment: Pass fake_globals as both globals and locals to the eval to mitigate attacks - `__builtins__` can't be accessed (nor any other Python name) if both dictionaries are changed: `In [15]: eval("__builtins__['zip']", FakeGlobals() )
Out[15]: zip` , 
`eval("__builtins__['zip']", FakeGlobals(), FakeGlobals() )
TypeError   string indices must be integers`

Comment: (for the above comment: the approach is not absolute, but it might mitigate naive attacks)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
tuples = [tuple(filter(None, t.strip('()').strip().split(','))) for t in input]
```

For example:

```
In [16]: tuples = [tuple(filter(None, t.strip('()').strip().split(','))) for t in input]

In [17]: tuples
Out[17]: [('var1',), ('var2', 'var3')]
```

We're iterating through our list of tuple strings, and for each one, removing the `()`s, then splitting our string into a list by the `,`, and then converting our list back into a tuple. We use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to remove empty elements.

Answer (score 4):

I like vaultah's solution. Here's another one with `ast.literal_eval` and `re` if `eval` is not an option:

```
>>> import re
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> [literal_eval(re.sub('(?<=\(|,)(\w+)(?=\)|,)', r'"\1"', x)) for x in input]
[('var1',), ('var2', 'var3')]
```