# Purpose of safe_eval in python odoo

Tags: python, odoo

the purpose of safe_eval in Python odoo? and use of safe_eval. I have checked with few custom modules, they have safe eval function.

Comment: Already asked?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369/is-safe-eval-really-safe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**safe_eval:**

- Module which contains methods intended to provide more restricted alternatives to evaluate simple and/or untrusted code.
- Methods in this module are typically used as alternatives to eval() to parse OpenERP domain strings, conditions and expressions, mostly based on locals condition/math builtins.

*Usage:*

```
safe_eval(expression[, globals[, locals[, mode[, nocopy]]]]) -> result
```

System-restricted Python expression evaluation

Evaluates a string that contains an expression that mostly
uses Python constants, arithmetic expressions and the
objects directly provided in context.

This can be used to e.g. evaluate
an OpenERP domain expression from an untrusted source.

- throws TypeError: If the expression provided is a code object
- throws SyntaxError: If the expression provided is not valid Python
- throws NameError: If the expression provided accesses forbidden names
- throws ValueError: If the expression provided uses forbidden bytecode

Comment: Thank u for ur rply.

Comment: @Annadurai You should mark the answer, as *the* answer by clicking in check mark.  Please, do so, it's good manners.

Comment: You should also note that `safe_eval` re-cast any other exception into ValueError.